# Charts using Highcharts with multiple series from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I have a JSON file of the following format :

```
[

  { name: 'Pay Off',
    data: [ [2850,0], 
            [3135,0], 
            [3420,0], 
            [3705,0], 
            [3990,0], 
            [4275,0], 
            [4560,0], 
            [4845,0], 
            [5130,0], 
            [5415,0], 
            [5700,0], 
            [5985,285],
            [6270,570], 
            [6555,855], 
            [6840,1140],
            [7125,1425],
            [7410,1710],
            [7695,1995],
            [7980,2280],
            [8265,2565],
            [8550,2850]
        ]
},

{
    name: 'Profit',
    data: [ [2850,-250],    
            [3135,-250],
            [3420,-250],
            [3705,-250],
            [3990,-250],
            [4275,-250],
            [4560,-250],
            [4845,-250],
            [5130,-250],
            [5415,-250],
            [5700,-250],
            [5985,35],
            [6270,320],
            [6555,605],
            [6840,890],
            [7125,1175],
            [7410,1460],
            [7695,1745],
            [7980,2030],
            [8265,2315],
            [8550,2600]
        ]
    }
]
```

I have to plot graph for 'Pay Off' and 'Profit' together. Even more plots maybe added to the list as per requirement. The data array has x-axis as 0th element and y-axis as 1st element. 
What I am currently doing is the following -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var options = {
      chart: {
          renderTo: 'container',
          type: 'line'
          },
    title: {
        text: 'PayOff Curve'
    },
    legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: []
};
$.getJSON('data.json', function(list) {
    var newseries = {
        name: '',
        data: []
    };

    $.each(list, function(i,item){
        newseries.name = item.name;
        newseries.data = item.data;
        options.series.push(newseries);    
    });

           // Create the chart
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
  });
```

But I don't any graph at all. I can't figure out the issue with it as I am new to both JavaScript and Python. Please suggest an efficient method to do this.
Thanks for your help..

Comment: `But there is some issue with it`. Are you going to tell us the issue, or are we supposed to guess?

Comment: I don't get any plot in this and I can't figure out the issue as I said because I am new to both JavaScript and Python. Please help it you know a method to do this task, ie, read data from JSON file in the given format and plot it using different lines in Highcharts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON isn't proper one, try to validate it. Properties names shold have double quotes, change from: `name: 'Pay Off'` to: `"name": "Pay Off"`

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is valid for a highcharts series - you don't need to try to transform it at all:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
          text: 'PayOff Curve'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: []
    };
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(list) {
        options.series = list; // <- just assign the data to the series property.
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }); 
});
```

If that still doesn't work, open the console to see whether there's a JavaScript error.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7TnJc/).

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work when I take the data from a JSON file. Also, there is no error on console. Reading data from file is a requirement.

Comment: When I tried to print the list being read form the file, there was no output. There must an error in the way I am trying to read the file. Please help me with it.

Comment: Assign a function to `.fail()` on the JSON request to see errors on the JSON request. Take a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to see how it's done.

Comment: Look at [Pawel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17527908/1402923). You're missing the quotes around your keys.