# Adding Multiple Series to Highcharts using a Json string

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, highcharts

At the moment I am creating 3 Json strings and adding the series at run time.

```
series: [  {  

name: userID,
showInLegend: true,  
color: '#6699cc',
data: <%= chartData%>  
},
{
name: 'High Alarm Value',
showInLegend: true,  
color: '#FF0000',
data: <%= chartDataMax%>  
},
{
name: 'Low Alarm Value',
showInLegend: true,  
color: '#0000FF',
data: <%= chartDataMin%>  
}
]
```

and loading them as you can see.  I want to create an array of Json strings with n number of series and add them to the graph.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33833711/create-highcharts-column-type-from-json/33844144#33844144

Comment: Thanks, but that only shows 1 series, I need multiple series, how to I create a Json string with multiple series?

Comment: what type of chart you want to plot ? column or pie?

Comment: I want something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526201/charts-using-highcharts-with-multiple-series-from-json but I need to pass it as I do above